# Test that $mdDialog resolve is calling the correct service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a simplified service that opens a dialog like this

```
service.open = args => {
    return $mdDialog.show({
        templateUrl: '...',
        controller: '...',
        controllerAs: '...',
        resolve: {
            mything: () => {
                return mything.get().$promise.then(data => data.data);
            }
        }
    })
};
```

In my test I inject `mything` service and spy on the `get` method. But it is never called when I call the `service.open` function.
I'd like to test that `mything.get()` is called, how do I go about doing that?

```
beforeEach(inject((_dialog_, _mything_) => {
    dialog = _dialog_;
    mything = _mything_;
}));

fit('should call correct resolve', () => {
    spyOn(mything , 'get');

    dialog.open(); // This is my service

    expect(mything.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Looks fine, though you don't need to resolve the `mything.get()` yourself ... the modal service will resolve it. Should just be `return mything.get();`